# jquery ui date picker icons messed up

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

im using jquery ui datepicker. for some reason i am experiencing strange behaviour with the icons. the word "next and "prev" are appearing over the top of the icons.
[image]

when i hover it the next and prev words show in red (my link hover color).

what is wrong? it was working previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was a bizarre bug.

an outer div containing the datepicker had a css style text-align right on it.
when i remove it it worked. weird.